# Can we use var as a return type of a function?

Tags: flutter, dart

Can we use `var` as the return type of a function in dart?

For example:

```
var add(var a,var b) => a+b;
```

This snippet of code was producing an error for me and I had to replace the `var` with `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Normally when we talk about "var" in Dart it means that it can be an int, double, or even a String, here we use a dynamic, which returns any value (int, double, etc) referring to whatever is inside your function. But you have to be sure that it can return something dynamic, if it is a sum then you return int.

```
  dynamic add(dynamic a, dynamic b) => a+b;
```

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour)

> var: A way to declare a variable without specifying its type. The type of this variable (int) is determined by its initial value (42).

If you want dynamic, you can remove return type or adding `dynamic` in this case.

```dart
dynamic add(var a, var b) => a + b;
```

or just

```dart
add(var a, var b) => a + b;
```

Answer (score -1):

replacing var with int is just declaring which type of variable a and b are.